# How to add jar files of GWT in Eclipse

Tags: gwt, jar, gwt-rpc

How to add jar files of GWT in Eclipse luna?
 Its ping me frequently for keeping update of plugins? what's the future scope of GWT?
Please guide me for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @cfulton. [Here](http://ask.electric-cloud.com/questions/3321/how-do-i-include-a-jar-file-in-a-gwt-plugin) I got success.

1. Create lib folder at same level as src folder.
2. Copy jar into lib folder.
3. Open up eclipse, or if you already have open refresh by going File->Refresh. 
   Ensure you can now see your jar file under Project->Lib.
4. Add library to build.xml file (create pathelement entry in `<path id="extras"> section <pathelement location="lib/gwt-bootstrap.jar"/>`
5. Add library to Build Path. 
    Right Click on project in Package Explorer, Build Path->Configure Build Path.
    Click “Add JARs” in the “Libraries” section.
    Navigate to the lib folder of your project and select the jar and click okay.
    Click okay on the configure build path dialog.
6. Add `<inherits>` tag.
   In file Component .gwt.xml add the following line (specific to what you are including). `<inherits name="com.github.gwtbootstrap.Bootstrap"/>`